# Translating customizer options with polylang

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I'm using this script: "https://themovation.helpscoutdocs.com/article/196-polylang-customizer-theme-ooptions" to translate the Customize options with 
Polylang.
However, whenever I apply the script the homepages change their permalinks into an old staged website that I deleted a while ago!
what's the problem?